# JWT Cookie is not stored right - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, jwt

I am using **Laravel 5.1** and i'm trying to implement a basic `JWT-Auth` logic.

While i'm creating the `jwt_token` right (i log it to `laravel.log`, token has it's three different parts divided by dot as expected), when i try to create a cookie with the `jwt_token` value, a completely different cookie is created, with no division by dots and it is much bigger than the original `jwt_token`.

I think code is pretty straightforward :

```
$jwt_token = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);
Log::error('My jwt_token is '. $jwt_token); //from the log here i see the right jwt_token

//i disable the http-only flag because i want to read it with js

return redirect('/index.html')->withCookie(Cookie::make('jwt_token',$jwt_token,1000,null,null,false,false));
```

I would be really glad, if anyone could give me some pointers about what may be wrong !

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel 5.1 ships by default with a middleware named `EncryptCookies` that is registered in the global `$middleware` array of the HTTP kernel. So the cookies are automatically encrypted when sent to the browser, that's why your cookie value is not the plain text representation of your JWT token.

You can easily fix that in two ways:

**1.** Add the cookie name to the `$except` array in the `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies`:

```
protected $except = [
    'jwt_token'
];
```

**2.** Comment/remove the `EncryptCookies` middleware in the `App\Http\Kernel` class (although I do not recommend this unless you specifically want all cookies to be unencrypted):

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer.

I should have read more carefully the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#cookies, you are right!